# Access document properties of Power Point file in C#

Tags: c#, properties, document, powerpoint

I need to access Power Point properties like Author, Organization..

How can I do that?

EDIT:

This is what I am trying:

```
static void TestProperties(Presentation presentation) // Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentation;
            {
                Microsoft.Office.Core.DocumentProperties properties;
                properties = (Microsoft.Office.Core.DocumentProperties)presentation.BuiltInDocumentProperties;

                Microsoft.Office.Core.DocumentProperty prop;

            }
```

This gives me ClassCastException:

Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Core.DocumentProperties'

I have a file chooser dialog where I choose the presentation and then pass it to TestProperties method.

Answer (score 2):

I have a working C# code to **read / write document properties** for **PowerPoint** documents, using OLE automation ([Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint/15.0.4420.1017)):

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint;
using System.Reflection;

class PowerPointConverterDocumentPropertiesReaderWriter
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Application pptApplication = new Application();
        Presentation presentation = pptApplication.Presentations.Open("presentation.pptx");

        object docProperties = presentation.BuiltInDocumentProperties;
        string title = GetDocumentProperty(docProperties, "Title").ToString();
        string subject = GetDocumentProperty(docProperties, "Subject").ToString();
        string author = GetDocumentProperty(docProperties, "Author").ToString();
        string category = GetDocumentProperty(docProperties, "Category").ToString();
        string keywords = GetDocumentProperty(docProperties, "Keywords").ToString();

        SetDocumentProperty(docProperties, "Title", "new title");
        SetDocumentProperty(docProperties, "Subject", "new subject");
        SetDocumentProperty(docProperties, "Author", "new author");
        SetDocumentProperty(docProperties, "Category", "new category");
        SetDocumentProperty(docProperties, "Keywords", "new keywords");
    }

    static object GetDocumentProperty(object docProperties, string propName)
    {
        object prop = docProperties.GetType().InvokeMember(
            "Item", BindingFlags.Default | BindingFlags.GetProperty,
            null, docProperties, new object[] { propName });
        object propValue = prop.GetType().InvokeMember(
            "Value", BindingFlags.Default | BindingFlags.GetProperty,
            null, prop, new object[] { });
        return propValue;
    }

    static void SetDocumentProperty(object docProperties, string propName, object propValue)
    {
        object prop = docProperties.GetType().InvokeMember(
            "Item", BindingFlags.Default | BindingFlags.GetProperty,
            null, docProperties, new object[] { propName });
        prop.GetType().InvokeMember(
            "Value", BindingFlags.Default | BindingFlags.SetProperty,
            null, prop, new object[] { propValue });
    }
}
```

Tested and works as expected with Microsoft PowerPoint for Office 365 (version 16.0).

Thanks to https://wditot.wordpress.com/2012/05/10/extracting-metadata-from-ms-office-docs-programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Will something like this work for you..? change the properties["      "] to fit your case

```
Microsoft.Office.Core.DocumentProperties properties;
properties = (Microsoft.Office.Core.DocumentProperties)
    Globals.ThisWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties; 
Microsoft.Office.Core.DocumentProperty prop;
prop = properties["Revision Number"];
```

Comment: Additionally (after adding the PowerPoint Com Object reference to your project of course), `Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentation` may be of use as well.

Comment: That's a great answer probably even better since .NET works well using Interop vs unmanaged COM.. +1 for Todd as well

Comment: @ToddBFisher I already have reference to `Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentation` object (presentation file I am interested in) in my code but I just can't find that information I need.

Comment: @DJ KRAZE I am trying the combination of both answers. Something like this: Microsoft.Office.Core.DocumentProperties properties = (Microsoft.Office.Core.DocumentProperties)presentation.BuiltInDocumentProperties;

but I get ClassCastException: Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Core.DocumentProperties'.

Comment: can you paste some of what code you have so we can take a look..perhaps you are missing something.. and it would be easier for others to see as well incase they would like to chime in..

Comment: Is it possible that this can only be done with Excel and Word? [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4e0tda25.aspx)